# active CSS pseudo-class and iscroll issue in firefox

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, pseudo-class, iscroll

I am developing a mobile website. I am using Jquery mobile and iscroll plugin. Everything works fine in chrome. But while checking in firefox i could find the **:active** css styles written for the elements are not working.

here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/zq5AW/

The active effect is working in chrome but not in firefox.

But when i removed the  jquery.mobile.iscrollview-min.js include line. It started working in firefox also. Can anyone suggest a fix?

> Note: Same question was found on googling
>
> https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/iscroll/lqPomh3y-TU
>
> But there was no answers.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or some form of a demo?

Comment: @Jrod: http://jsfiddle.net/zq5AW/

Comment: jsmobile sucks is my personal experiance, just make your website like any normal website but on boilerplate - http://html5boilerplate.com/
(boilerplate is a mobile optimize "template" to build your websites on so they load faster)

Comment: @SimonPertersen : you mean to say jquery mobile sucks? or iscroll?

Comment: Dont really know iscroll but its seems like my easing scroll project would be a gr8 solution https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dv0lcdwg71m8bt2/VrOPVOq6pz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mithunsatheesh, you have a conflict in between two libraries - jQuery and jQuery Mobile. Are you sure that you need two libraries loading at the same time?

If you change the order the way you load your libraries, then everything will work and you will get desired result:

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2eQSa/)

Other than that, I could offer you another solution, which would be just to use jQuery to get desired effect, as I don't see any other working possibility:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").mousedown(function() {
        $(this).addClass('hovered');
    }).mouseup(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hovered');
    });
});
```

[Working Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/zc4DL/)

#### UPDATED:

Referring to your last comment, here is my final solution for you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").mousedown(function() {
        hovered = true;
        $(this).addClass('hovered');
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function() {
        if (hovered === true) {
            $("p").removeClass('hovered');
            hovered = false;
        }
    });
});
```

[Working Example 3](http://jsfiddle.net/zm66p/)

Comment: In your example isroll effect is lost due to order. Try clicking on the firefox text in your fiddle and drag. It drags in the fiddle i posted and now iscroll effect is lost. Please look into that. Thanks for the effort bro.

Comment: You are welcome! I expected that there would be other subsequent problems. Could you tell me why do you load two versions on one page? Why don't you separate mobile version and desktop one? You would make it lighter on both platforms and make life easier?

Comment: Bro. all the libraries included are required to get iscroll working with jquery mobile.. as in https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview

Comment: I see the way they are included - just like you did. Try putting them on you local host first. I downloaded that library and everything in the library worked fine for me. Did you read this as well: https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview#event-and-callback-option-functions

Comment: If you could provide me with the concrete file that isn't working from downloaded archive, that would be easier! Or it's only happening with your content?

Comment: dude test it in firefox add a content with some :active psedo css defined inside the scroller div , it will not work. Is there any fix is my qn.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh: I have updated my answer. I think this is the last solution that I could offer, my friend! Hope it will work right for you.

Comment: @Ohh. Besides Jrod just added the same solution. Ahh.. Didn't see. I'm voting up for Jrod.

Comment: when i clicked and dragged on the *firefox* text it gets the hover effect. But once i am out of it.. the hover effect doesnt get removed. Sorry if i am wrong.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh Please check my updated answer. :) Good luck to you with your scripting!

Answer (score 2):

I wish I could say for certain what is causing the problem but I can't.  My understanding of the issue is that something in that javascript file is preventing default browser actions that would normally trigger the `:active` pseudo class.

You can work around this by adding and removing a class to the element on mousedown/mouseup

CSS

```
.act { color:#000; }
.act:active, .active { color:#FFF; }​
```

JS

```
$('.act').mousedown(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$('.act').mouseup(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

Here is a working fiddle too:
http://jsfiddle.net/zq5AW/3/

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice. Wrote just the same additional solution to my answer and right after saw yours. Vote up for you.

Comment: @Jrod : bro.. just one issue. when i clicked and dragged on the *firefox* text it gets the hover effect. But once i am out of it.. the hover effect doesnt get removed. Sorry if i am wrong.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh You could modify the mouseup event to be on the document so any mouse up with trigger the function and remove the class `active` from `.act` here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/zq5AW/5/